# How can I overlay 2 binary images to save the white color on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, image-processing

Imagine there're two the same binary images (all pixels are black). And then you take the 1st image and make some of the pixels white (e.g., points `(10,10)` and `(11, 11)`) and do the same operation for point `(5, 4)` of the 2nd image and save the result images as `image1.png` and `image2.png`.

The goal is to create the third image (`result.png`) that will have every pixel as black but 3 points: `(5, 4)`, `(10,10)`, and `(11,11)` that should be white. How can I do this operation in Ubuntu automatically?

[composite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/composite-im6.1.html) looks like a good command to look into. I tried to use `composite -blend` and then didn't manage to find the correct command to save the white color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composite -blend 100x100% image1.png image2.png output.png` worked for me.

[image: image1.png]
image1.png

[image: image2.png]
image2.png

[image: output.png]
output.png

See [the documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#blend) for more info.